# getting datas from XML : NetSuite WebService

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, netsuite

I want to get data from `NetSuite WebService`. This is how my code looks like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    WebServiceGenesisSoapClient service;
    public HomeController()
    {
        var aa = WebServiceGenesisSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.WebServiceGenesisSoap;
        service = new WebServiceGenesisSoapClient(aa);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        WebServiceGenesisSoapClient client = new WebServiceGenesisSoapClient(aa, "http://82.71.28.125/WebServiceGenesis/WebServiceGenesis.asmx");

        GetStockQuantityArrayRequest getStockQuantityArrayRequest = new GetStockQuantityArrayRequest();
        var stocklist = client.GetStockQuantityArrayAsync(getStockQuantityArrayRequest).Result;
        ArrayOfXElement res = stocklist.GetStockQuantityArrayResult;
    }
}
```

Two Nodes are present in `res` variable.  This is how first node looks like:

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="StockQuantityArray">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Colour" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Quantity1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Quantity2" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Quantity3" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is how my second node looks like:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
```

If datas are present in response, they are present in second node. If datas are not present, I want to get value of `name` attribute inside `xs:sequence` element of first node.

**EDIT 1:** If datas are present , then first node looks like:

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Departments">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and second node looks like:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    <Departments diffgr:id="Departments1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Code>ALL</Code>
      <Description>ALL</Description>
    </Departments>
    <Departments diffgr:id="Departments2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
      <Code>BABY</Code>
      <Description>BABY</Description>
    </Departments>
    <Departments diffgr:id="Departments3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
      <Code>CHIL</Code>
      <Description>CHILD</Description>
    </Departments>
    <Departments diffgr:id="Departments4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
      <Code>TEEN</Code>
      <Description>TEEN</Description>
    </Departments>
    <Departments diffgr:id="Departments5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
      <Code>WM</Code>
      <Description>WOMAN</Description>
    </Departments>
  </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
        XmlNode secondNode = getSecondNode();// read the second node from the res
        if (secondNode != null)
        {
            XmlNodeList xnList = secondNode.SelectNodes("//NewDataSet//Departments");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string code = xn.SelectSingleNode("Code") != null ? xn.SelectSingleNode("Code").Value : "";
                string Description = xn.SelectSingleNode("Description") != null ? xn.SelectSingleNode("Description").Value : "";
            }
        }
        else
        {

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            XmlNode firstNode = getFirstNode();// read the first node from the res
            XmlNodeList xnList = firstNode.SelectNodes("//bk:sequence//bk:element", nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string value = ((System.Xml.XmlElement)xn).Attributes["name"].Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first xml is a schema that does not contain any data.  The schema just list the possible object that can be returned in the 2nd xml.  I would need to see some examples of the 2nd file with actual data responses to be able to give a good answer.

Comment: This is the last line of the question "If datas are not present, I want to get value of name attribute inside xs:sequence element of first node."
So this might help to get the values from first node.

Comment: @jdweng sir I have edited my question to present data format while datas are present.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication122
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsDiffgr = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("diffgr");
            XNamespace nsData = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("msdata");

            List<Department> deparments = doc.Descendants(ns + "Departments").Select(x => new Department()
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute(nsDiffgr + "id"),
                code = (string)x.Element(ns + "Code"),
                description = (string)x.Element(ns + "Description"),
                rowOrder = (int)x.Attribute(nsData + "rowOrder")
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Department> dict = deparments
                .GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
    public class Department
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int rowOrder { get;set;}
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir, I need to get name of elements if data not present

Comment: How do you get the name of something that doesn't exist?  You could make a list of all the the data types and then check if the item is in list or not in list.

Comment: if datas are not present then response will be in same format as mentioned in question.

Comment: The first xml has the property in the schema : minOccurs="0" which means the property can be empty.   As I said the only way of finding missing objects is to create a list of all properties and then test the possible list of properties against the list the was received. It looks like the two schemas you posted are from different types of responses.  The first is from "StockQuantityArray" and the second is from "Departments" (same as xml posted).  Why are you getting different schema formats?